# In a shell script, how can you combine both `Rscript` and `Unix` commands?

Tags: linux, r

I am currently trying to run an R file as an Rscript file. I have the following code inside a `script.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd documents
module load r

#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
mem2 <- 4+5
packageVersion("data.table")
save.image("OUT.RData")
```

However, it appears that after running this using `qsub script.sh`, it comes back with errors saying how several commands were not recognized. Am I doing this wrong? Thanks!

Comment: That's all in the same file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for a "Here document" in the shell.  That allows text to be passed to another interpreter.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd documents
module load r

/usr/bin/env Rscript -<<EOF
mem2 <- 4+5
packageVersion("data.table")
save.image("OUT.RData")
EOF
```

Here, the `Rscript` is called (from `/usr/bin/env`) and on the standard input, all of the subsequent lines are passed until the marker (here, `EOF`) is seen.